# Different ways of returning hard coded values via SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have some data that is hard coded in my select query.

The SQL is as follows:

```
SELECT 
'ZZ0027674',
'ZZ0027704',
'ZZ0027707',
'ZZ0027709',
'ZZ0027729',
'ZZ0027742',
'ZZ0027750'
```

Unfortunately it does not display the data. It just returns 7 columns and each column has each value. I just want 1 column with the different values.

Please provide me different solutions to display the data?

Comment: Check the rest of query, probably `WHERE ...` is false for you case

Comment: Extra points if someone can show me unpivot ?

Comment: Can you provide sample output?  When you say "it just returns 7 columns" do you mean 7 rows (ie vertical not horizontal)?

Comment: Why are you trying to refer to a table called `ORDER`, especially if you are hard-coding values? If you _do_ have a table called `ORDER` somewhere, then (A) that's not a good idea as that's a keyword, but (B) put `[delimiters]` around it if you must use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`VALUES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx), aka *Table Value Constructor*, clause for hardcoded values:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('ZZ0027674'),('ZZ0027704'),('ZZ0027707'),
            ('ZZ0027709'),('ZZ0027729'),('ZZ0027742'),
             ('ZZ0027750')
     ) AS sub(c)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415356)**</kbd>

*Warning:* This has limitation up to 1000 rows and applies to `SQL Server 2008+`. For lower version you could use `UNION ALL` instead.

**EDIT:**

> Extra points if someone can show me unpivot ?

```
SELECT col
FROM (SELECT 'ZZ0027674','ZZ0027704','ZZ0027707',
             'ZZ0027709','ZZ0027729','ZZ0027742','ZZ0027750'
     ) AS sub(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)
UNPIVOT
(
   col for c in (v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7)
) AS unpv;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/415373)**</kbd>

Comment: Only for SQL Server 2008 and above.

Comment: @Horaciux Yes, added note about it.

Answer (score 5):

Use union:

```
  SELECT 
'ZZ0027674' union all
SELECT 'ZZ0027704' union all
SELECT 'ZZ0027707' union all
SELECT 'ZZ0027709' union all
SELECT 'ZZ0027729' union all
SELECT 'ZZ0027742' union all
SELECT 'ZZ0027750'
```

Comment: All SQL Server version compatible

Answer (score 1):

Can also use union

```
SELECT 'ZZ0027674' as [col1] 
UNION 
SELECT 'ZZ0027704'
```